# Rebase branch to branch on github

Tags: github

I contribute to a public repo on github. Another user (X-name) has fork of the repo with a branch with some changes he stopped working on. I would like to "clone" his branch into my repo as a local branch.
I have X-names repo as a remote already.

How do i do that, also so i later on can PR to the Public main repo?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you have to remote forked repo by

```
git remote add xname-fork https://github.com/X-name/repo.git
```

then you can fetch changes with `git fetch xname-fork`

after all you can create a branch for save it

```
git checkout -b local-branch-name xname-fork/xname-branch
```

you on local-branch-name right now let's add changes with

```
git add .
git commit -m "feat: some commit desc"
git push origin local-branch-name
```

now you can create a pull request `local-branch-name` to `master` (or `main` whatever your base branch)

Done.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I use Visual studio code, so need to familiar with git commands. So just to clarify/ specify.

Lets call the main repo "shop"
Lets call the other contributor witch i wanna clone his branch "contributor"
Lets call his repo "shop-1"
Lets call his branch "feature"
Lets call my repo "shop-2"

I already have remote and upstream for the main repo "shop". And also added PRs before.

Can you update this code so i understand it correctly :-)

Comment: `git remote add contributor-fork https://github.com/contributor/shop-1.git` | 
`git fetch contributor-fork` | 
`git checkout -b feature contributor-fork/feature` | 
`git add .` | 
`git commit -m "feat: some commit desc"`| 
`git push origin feature/branch-name(this on your choice)` | 

then you can create pull request from github repo.